# I want to make a channel that is only visible for admins discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
async def report(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, report=None):
    report_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("reports")
    await report_channel.set_permissions(has_permissions(administrator=True), view_channel=True, add_reactions=True)
# I tried to fix it every time but it never works i just want to make that specific report channel to be only visible for admins :(
```

I keep getting this error:
Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is pretty clear.

`channel.set_permissions` takes a member or role object as its argument.

You don't need to use it anyway, you can simply use the `overwrites` argument of `ctx.guild.create_text_channel`:

```py
everyone = ctx.guild.default_role
# Gets the @everyone role, see: https:#discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.default_role
ctx.guild.
overwrites = {everyone: discord.PermissionOverwrite.from_pair(deny=discord.Permissions.all(), allow=[])
ctx.guild.get_role(admin_role_snowflake): discord.PermissionOverwrite.from_pair(deny=discord.Permissions.none(), allow=discord.Permissions.all_channel())}
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("reports", overwrites=overwrites)
# see: https:#discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel
```

The first dict item declares that @everyone should not have any permissions for that channel by default.

The second declares that the admin role should have all text channel permissions for that channel.

You might need to adjust the permissions to get your desired result and make sure to replace `admin_role_snowflake` with the snowflake of the admin role in the server.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. If I use `ctx.guild.overwrites` it says that `Guild` doesn't have attribute `overwrites` if I just omit `ctx.guild` it crashes inside the text channel creation due to some internal error (NoneType has no `ID`)